# How to use scheduled task to backup mysql database

Tags: automation, mysql, task-scheduler

I am using mysqldump to backup mysql database. I have created a batch file that would do it for me, and I used task scheduler to do it automatically. But everytime it launches it, it always prompt for a password, which requires user intervention, what would I do with this. Any other ways that you know on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `--password` option to mysqldump you can specify the password to use so that it doesn't have to prompt you. Add `--password=<yourpassword>` to the command that you use to invoke mysqldump in the batch script.

Answer (score 1):

There is an Open Source script called automysqlbackup that has some good features, including auto login and dated backups - worth a study.

sourceforge.net/projects/automysqlbackup/